# yValues position on a BarChart

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I am developing a `Swift 4` application and am using the `Charts 3.0.4` cocoapod. I managed to draw a `BarChart` but now I want to put the values of each bar within the bar itself. I find how to change the font of the values by using the `.setValueFont` method of the `BarCharDataSet` but I am not able to find how to change their positions.

Please take a look at the images for better understanding! 
Thanks in advance!

Currently:
[image: Currently]

Goal:
[image: Goal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line:

```
chart.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = false
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!